# How are config files read by linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration

I am new to config files and I wanted to know how linux reads config files. For example if a config file contains duplicates, does it show an error or reads the last occurrence?

This is a snippet from sshd_config file:

```
X11Forwarding yes
AllowAgentForwarding yes
PermitRootLogin yes
X11Forwarding no
```

Since there are two `X11Forwarding` keyword argument, does it take the first occurrence or the last occurrence? Do duplicates cause error?

Comment: It's up to the program reading the configuration. It's just a text file, and there is no general unified format. Are you in particular interested in the `sshd_config` that you show? Is this question about that configuration file in particular?

Comment: I don't have a particular configuration file in mind. Just in a general sense. But your answer makes sense

Comment: That was a comment to figure out your intention, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for commenting !

Comment: As a side-note to the existing answers and comments, the configuration of system services (such as `systemd`, `dhcp` ) is usually implemented such that if a duplicate entry is found, it overrrides the previous setting. This is because it is standard now for such services to have one small "default" config file  `/etc/some-service.conf` (read first) and a directory `/etc/some-service.conf.d/` with "config file snippets" (read in filename sort order, so they begin with numbers) that other packages can install to override default settings without having to modify the global config file.

Answer (score 3):

In the relevant sense it is not Linux that reads those files but applications. They are in no way forced to use the same config file format or handle situations in the same way.

For several programs I have read that if there are different settings for the same value on the command line then the last one was used. I assume that this is the typical approach for config files (at least if the order of entries does not matter).

So you have to ask your question for each relevant application separately. For a single application it is easy to get the answer. Just try both versions and see what happens. On the other hand that does not guarantuee that future versions of that application will behave the same way. That is probable, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely dependent on the implementation of the software that reads and parses the configuration file. Sometimes there's an error, sometimes the first entry is considered and sometimes the last entry is the one that takes effect.

There is no overarching process that controls reading and parsing of configuration files.